# Delete INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-design, mariadb, information-schema

I recently created a new database and INFORMATION_SCHEMA was there. I am aware that users should not mess with backend services, but INFORMATION_SCHEMA has 0 bytes. I checked all the tables and there was nothing inside. Is it safe to delete INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Comment: The ISO-standard SQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` catalog views support meta-data queries. Why do you want to delete them?

Comment: You can't drop it in SQL Server anyway.

Comment: Fairly sure sure they can't be deleted in mysql/mariadb either.  There's no implementation to do anything apart from read from them. The most that can go wrong is a) reading causes a server crash, or excessive CPU/IO usage, or b) the user can read a table name which isn't there. Due to the age of the implementation these are protected against and aren't likely. So, don't worry about it, worry about the users writing SQL injection vulnerable code.

Comment: Which version of which product??